# How to equalize width of cells of tables and center texts in cells (horizontally)

Tags: tables

I am trying to add some mathematical formulations and using tables for them. My code for overleaf is below:

```
\begin{flushleft}
\textit{INDICES}
\end{flushleft}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{ll}
\midrule
\textit{i}& counter for employee number, \textit{i} = 1,2,…,\textit{N};\\
\midrule
\textit{m} & counter for category  number, \textmd{m} = 1,2,…,\textit{M}.\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}\\[10pt]
\end{table}

\begin{flushleft}
\textit{DECISION VARIABLES}
\end{flushleft}

\begin{flushleft}
\textit{Continuous Variables}
\end{flushleft}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{ll}
\midrule
\textit{\begin{math}X_m\end{math}}& increase percentage cor-responding to category \textit{m}.\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}\\[10pt]
\end{table}

\begin{flushleft}
\textit{Binary Variables}
\end{flushleft}

\begin{table}[h]
\small\sf\centering
\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{ll}
\midrule
\textit{\begin{math}Z_m\end{math}}& 1, if employee \textit{i} is given salary treatment \textit{m}, 0 otherwise.\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}\\[10pt]
\end{table}
```

**I need to first equalize the cell widths so that everything looks nice (even though the second cells can go to the second line). Also center text in cells. Additionally, with my code, a huge paragraph space occurs after tables and "Continuous variable" and "Random Variables" headings. Basically, I want the following format:**
[image: As seen in the picture, I am using two column page.]

As seen in the picture, I am using two column page. And, there are more tables than these three (on the left).

Comment: Here are some hints: (1) You don't need `table` in order to use `tabular`; (2) `tabular` cannot be broken midway across the page boundary - the cause of your "huge paragraph spaces".

Comment: when I delete the     table beginning and ending, the table shifts to right and goes out of column. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Add `\noindent` before each `tabular` to avoid it being indented.

Comment: Code such as `\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{ll}` has very little chance of producing material that spans the width of the column. Do provide an `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` directive, i.e., write `\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l}`.

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of this approach is that it breaks over pages.  Note: you don't have to use the same width for the left and right boxes.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\newlength{\boxwidth}

\newcommand{\mytabs}[2]% $1 = left box, #2 = right box
{\parbox{\boxwidth}{#1}\hfill\parbox{\boxwidth}{#2}\newline}

\newcommand{\myrule}{\ifvmode\else\newline\fi
  \rule[.6\baselineskip]{\columnwidth}{.1ex}\vspace{-.6\baselineskip}\newline}% total height = 0.4\baselineskip

\begin{document}
\parindent=0pt
\parskip=0.5\baselineskip
\boxwidth=\dimexpr 0.5\columnwidth - \tabcolsep\relax

\textit{INDICES}
\myrule
\mytabs{\textit{i}}{counter for employee number, \textit{i} = 1,2,…,\textit{N};}
\myrule
\mytabs{\textit{m}}{counter for category  number, \textmd{m} = 1,2,…,\textit{M}.}
\myrule

\textit{DECISION VARIABLES}

\textit{Continuous Variables}
\myrule
\mytabs{\textit{$X_m$}}{increase percentage cor-responding to category \textit{m}.}
\myrule

\textit{Binary Variables}
\begingroup
\small\sf
\myrule
\mytabs{\textit{$Z_m$}}{1, if employee \textit{i} is given salary treatment \textit{m}, 0 otherwise.}
\myrule
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Aims

In your question, you refered the following points

1. inserting mathematical formulations/formulae
2. The cell content (in the second column?) should be centered.
3. The width of some columns should be the same in each table.

Maybe I have missed some other concerns?

## Solution

Therefore I changed your MWE heavily.

1. Mathematical formulae: if you load the `array`-package, you can define new column types and you can run LaTeX commands, each time, you enter that column or leave that column.  I used the `\newcolumntype` to define at least two new column types, one for the left column and one for the right column.  I also used the `>{}` and `<{}`-command to run the LaTeX-commands.  See the `array`-manual for further details (or my comments in the MWE).

   For the left column, I put it into math mode, by defining something like `>{$} l <{$}`.  (This is only an example, the real code looks a bit different.)  In this example, I created a column, which will be flush left aligned and which is automatically in math mode.  Instead of typing `\begin{math} i \end{math}`, you can type `i`.  Rather handy, I'd say.
2. The same trick was applied, to define the second column to be aligned horizontal centered.  This time, I decided to use `\Centering`-command, which is defined in package `ragged2e`.  You have to load that package in the preamble before.  The great advantage of the this package/command is, that it is able, to split words, instead of only in between words.  Therefore you get a much more elegant distribution of words on your lines.  To make the example work correct, you have to add `\arraybackslash` also.  See the MWE for the complete code.
3. You want to have the same width on the according columns for each table, you define.  To realize this task, you can utilize a `p{<width>}` column type.

   Unfortunately, a `p`-column justifies the text, which is in contrast to your wish, to have the text centered.  See 2. how to solve this problem.

   It is rather easy, to define a new dimension, in order to have the `p`-columns all the same width.  Another great advantage is, that you only have to change the value of that dimension, in order to manipulate all the tables accordingly.  Yet there is the question, how wide the first column has to be.  Fortunately, using package `tabularx` and its `X`-column solves this problem without ease.  The `X`-column in conjunction with the definition `\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}` will take up all remaining space until the total width of the table reaches `\columnwidth` (whatever that is).

## Some more changes

### Floating Objects

You defined in your code `\begin{table} ... \end{table}`.  A table is a floating environment.  This kind of environment gives LaTeX the opportunity, to move the content of that environment from the location, where it is defined in the input to a location of the output, where the best possible page break could be achieved.  The best page break---or should I say the best distribution of greyness on all pages---is important for readability.  If you define the floating option `[h]`, to suppress the floating ability, rendering the floating environment **useless**.

You also don't use `\caption`-commands, which should be obligatory on every floating environment, as you have to refer from the running text to the float by its number.  As you didn't create the float-number and neither set a label with it, I consider, that you really don't wanted to use a floating element.  I therefore stripped the `\begin{table} ... \end{table}` from your code.

### White space behind your tables

You were complaining about the "huge paragraph space occurs [that occurs] after tables".  This is due to the fact, that you are trying to combine a floating object and an anchored text.  LaTeX has no other chance to fullfill your demands (stated in your code), as it did in the output you got.  Have mercy with LaTeX and change your code.

### Elegancy

You have enabled the usage of package `booktabs` in your MWE.  Therefore I did the next step in creating an elegant table, by removing the unnecessary white space on the margins of the table.  You can do so by adding `@{}` in the table declaration on its left and right side.  As I utilized `\newcolumntype`, you will find the code in that definition.

### Proof of column width

I added another row in the first table, to proof the effect of the width of the second column as well of the beautiful distribution of the `\Centering`-command from package `ragged2e`.  The text was taken from en.wikipedia.org.  If there is enough text, ragged2e's `\Centering` will use the full cell width.  If there is less text, as is in your examples, it tries to distribute the text more evenly.  Therefore the line lengths decreases, which looks, as if the cell was narrower, that it really is.  I hope you don't mind me adding this proof.

### Further streamlining

You could even define a new command, to type the combination of section like title and the according table.

Something like the following in your preamble.

```
\newenvironment{mathtable}[1]{%
  \textit{#1}\par%
  \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{M}
  \toprule}{%
    \bottomrule%
    \end{tabularx}}
```

and use it in your document as

```
\begin{mathtable}{Continuous Variables}
  $X_m$ & increase percentage cor-responding to category $m$.\\ 
\end{tabularx}
```

Maybe you could even put something like `\MakeUppercase{#1}` into that environment, to format the titles in a unique fashion.

## MWE

Here is my MWE.   I put a lot of comments in the code.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

%% Define some text layout variables
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{2ex plus0.3ex minus0.1ex}

%% Define new column types.  Question was: the second columns shall
%% have allways the same width.  Therefore the first column has to be
%% of variable width. The left column is left aligned and always in
%% italics. 
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\itshape\selectfont\RaggedRight\arraybackslash} X}
%% Second column should be centerd.  I use the p-column-type in order
%% to define its width manually.
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
%% To have the width unique, I define a new length.  If this length
%% doesn't fit, change it once and have the effect everywhere.
\newlength{\secondcolwidth}
\setlength{\secondcolwidth}{0.8\columnwidth}
%% Finally, To save further typing labour, define a combining new
%% column.
\newcolumntype{M}{@{} LC{\secondcolwidth} @{}}
%% Alternatively, you could ommit the above newlength and setlength by
%% defining the new M column like this:
% \newcolumntype{M}[1]{@{} LC{#1} @{}}
%% In that case, you have to code the tabular like this:
%   \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{M{5cm}}
%% I prefer the above, as you have to change only one value to affect
%% all tables.

\begin{document}
%% What should the flushleft-environment be good for in this case?
\textit{INDICES}

%% I deleted the table environment, as it is a floating environment,
%% which you don't want to use, as you defined the floating option
%% [h].  It takes the table ad absurdum.
%% Use the new defined column types.  I order to save space on the
%% left and right margin on the table, suppres the empty white space
%% with "@{}".
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{M}
  \toprule
  %% Use math mode for the mathematical expression.
  %% use \ldots to print the ellipsis (...)
  i & counter for employee number, $i = 1,2,\ldots,N$;\\ 
  \midrule
  m & counter for category  number, $m = 1,2,\ldots,M$.\\ 
  \midrule
  $e$ & The number $e$ is a mathematical constant that is the base of
        the natural logarithm: the unique number whose natural
        logarithm is equal to one. It is approximately equal to
        2.71828 and is the limit of $(1 + 1/n)n$ as $n$ approaches
        infinity, an expression that arises in the study of compound
        interest. It can also be calculated as the sum of the infinite
        series \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}


\textit{DECISION VARIABLES}

\textit{Continuous Variables}

\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{M}
  \toprule
  $X_m$ & increase percentage cor-responding to category $m$.\\ 
  \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\textit{Binary Variables}

\small\sf
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{M}
  \toprule
  $Z_m$ & 1, if employee $i$ is given salary treatment $m$, 0
          otherwise.\\ 
  \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

## Result

This is the outcome.  I hope you like it. Please play around with `\setlength{secondcolwidth}{<width}` to adapt the look of the tables to your needs.

[image]